# How can I generate IBAN for Swedish Account number

Tags: java, iban

**Problem statement**
I have a Swedish Bank (SEB) account number and I need to generate the IBAN for this account number (in java code)

**A possibility**
I can see that it's possible if I use website: https://www.ibancalculator.com/

**What I tried**
https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/iban4j

```
Iban iban = new Iban.Builder()
                .countryCode(CountryCode.SE)
                .bankCode("XXXX")
                .accountNumber("XXXXXXX")
                .build();
```

Here X is a digit in my account number and the account number is overall 11 digits long (first 4 are clearing number and next 7 is account number).

However, when I try this, I get the following: `length is 11, expected BBAN length is: 20`

Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong here OR is there some other better way.

P.S. If I use same values on the ibancalculator.com, I get the correct IBAN for my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you obtain gives a hint that you need to use full length of the account number as indicated in [this example](https://www.xe.com/ibancalculator/sample/?ibancountry=sweden):

```
Iban iban = new Iban.Builder()
            .countryCode(CountryCode.SE)
            .bankCode("500")
            .accountNumber("0000005839825746")
            .build();
```

In other words, ensure that you are supplying expected 20 digits before calling `.build()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, it worked for the bank account number that I have :)
To be 100% sure, this bank code that you have listed above "500", is it specific for each bank or works for every bank in Sweden?

Comment: @ShankeyJain – bank code specifies the bank which hosts given account number `0000005839825746` so it must refer to the exact bank. If the answer worked for you, please see [tour] on how you can close it (and optionally also vote for helpful answers).

Comment: I agree that the answer worked for me, but it's more of a specific answer (will work with one bank only). I was more looking for a generic solution. So, I agree your answer is helpful but not complete. I will upvote it.

Comment: @ShankeyJain – but did you do any research? All [Swedish bank codes in IBAN have 3 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#IBAN_formats_by_country). To give you a codebook for all Swedish banks is outside the scope of this site. You asked why your library method call does not work and you obtained the working answer pointing to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The digits you putted in the bank code and in the account number are totally 11, but the iban requires 20 digits.

As you can see in the GitHub reference, you must put all the digits, so add the four digits you mentioned ("first 4 are clearing number") in the accountNumber and add the necessary digits in the bank code.